# how to input unicode character via summernote into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, unicode, wysiwyg, summernote

i try to input unicode character like " សួស្តី " into database via summernote but in database it display ??? instead of the unicode caracter, in database colliation i use latin_general_bin2 since the before i use summernote it could display unicode correctly, sorry may i know the correct way to do this.
[image]

above image  is data inputed in database

[image]

and this is the data that i submit before it in database

[image]

and this is collation that i used

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? How is the column `Description` defined in the database?

Comment: yes, i used ssms, and description defined in database also

Comment: So you use Micrsosoft SQL Server? And the column is defined as NVARCHAR?

Comment: thank you, i just find out the problem, and as you mention, it cause by the column is text  not nvarchar. i solved it